# Configure integration test or use Spring JDBC in Unit Test using Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, junit, spring-boot, integration-testing, spring-jdbc

Am using the latest versions of Spring Boot, Spring JDBC, and Spring Rest...

My project is setup as a typical Maven project containing the following filesystem structure:

```
myproject
|
--src/main/java/com/myapp
--src/main/resource/application.properties
|
--src/test/java/com/myapp
--src/test/resources/application.properties
|
pom.xml
```

My application.properties are as follows (connecting to a local MySQL 5 database):

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.name=testdb
spring.datasource.initialize=true
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

MyDAO:

```
public interface MyDao {

    public List<App> findAllApps(); 
}
```

MyDaoImpl:

```
@Repository("myDao")
public class MyDaoImpl implements MyDao {

    @Autowired 
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public List<App> findAllApps() {
        List<App> apps = this.jdbcTemplate.query(
                "select app_name from app",
                new RowMapper<App>() {
                    public App mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                        App app = new App();
                        app.setAppName(rs.getString("app_name"));
                        return app;
                    }
                });

        return apps;
    }
}
```

Its called in MyService class using Dependency Injection:

```
@RestController
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myDao")
    MyDao myDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/apps", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "text/plain", produces = "application/json")
    public void process() throws JsonParseException, IOException {
        List<App> apps = myDao.findAllApps();
        System.out.println(apps.toString());
    }
}
```

This totally works as stated in my RestController...

But however, in a typical JUnit test:

```
public class MyServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myDao")
    MyDao myDao;

    @Test
    public void process() {
        List<App> apps = myDao.findAllApps();
    }
}
```

The call to myDao.findAllApps() returns a NullPointerException...

I even tried running my app (using the embedded tomcat) first by issuing the following from the command line:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

However a non-database specific JUnit test works inside Eclipse or when I do:

```
mvn clean install
```

Question(s):

1. How can I set it up so I can run an integration test and it actually hits my database (or a mock db for that matter) from MyServiceTest?
2. Why is the dependency injection failing when trying to inject in MyServiceTest for Spring JDBC?
3. Is there a way to setup my unit tests to test Rest calls?

Many thanks for everyone who took the time to read this and many many thanks for the people that respond!

Here's my pom.xml (per Eddu's request):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>org.jboss.repository.releases</id>
            <name>JBoss Maven Release Repository</name>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <name>Spring Releases</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Can you attach the pom.xml?

Comment: Eddu, I edited my original post and appended the contents of the full pom.xml file per your request.

Comment: are you using spring-data-jpa in your app? Or you are using JdbcTemplate for custom repositories?

Comment: Eddu, JdbcTemplate its listed above in MyDaoImpl... Thanks for trying to help me.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you aren't loading Spring's context in your test so the dependency injection isn't performed. You should do something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes=Application.class) //Application being your
// Spring boot base config class
public class MyServiceTest { ... }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("myDao")
    MyDao myDao;
```

You can have a look at an example in my [github](https://github.com/codependent/spring-boot-java8-sample/blob/master/src/test/java/com/josesa/jdk18/test/StreamTest.java)

Comment: Given that it's Spring Boot, then `@SpringApplicationConfiguration` may be better than `@ContextConfiguration` so that it uses the `SpringApplicationContextLoader`.

Comment: WornOutSoles, Thanks for responding... Why inject the jdbcTemplate instead of my Dao?

Comment: Steve, can you please provide an example? Is there a way to make the server (or a different server) run when then JUnit test is invoked?

Comment: Take into account the configuration to run the test in spring context. Moreover, if you are not using spring-data-jpa change the current spring-starter-data-jpa dependency by spring-boot-starter-jdbc which allow to auto-configure the JdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone!

Steve - you were correct!

After much trial & tribulation, the @SpringApplicationConfiguration worked:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes=Application.class)
```

Eddu Melendez - I removed the spring-starter-data-jpa dependency with spring-boot-starter-jdbc and also removed the spring-jdbc dependency from my pom.xml file.

Thank you all for trying to help me solve this issue!